# AJAX array stopping AJAX call

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, vb.net

Please see the AJAX code below:

```
function Save()
        {

            var checkBoxArray = $("input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                return this.id
            }).get();

            var str = JSON.stringify(checkBoxArray);
                var user = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lstUsers");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "frmReview.aspx/AllocateReview",
                    data: '{strUser: "' + user.value + '", strCheckBoxes: ' + str + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess(),
                async: false,
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert('There was a problem allocating the reviews')
                }
                });

                function OnSuccess() {
                    return function (response) {
                        alert("The reviews where allocated successfully");
                    }
                }
     }
```

and the server side code below:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Sub AllocateReview(ByVal strUser As String, ByVal strCheckBoxes As String)
       msgbox("got here")
    End Sub
```

I put a breakpoint on the messagebox (server side).  However, it is not reached.  It is reached if I do not pass str (which is an array) i.e. I exclude it on the client side and server side.  Why is the array not passed to the server? There is no error - it is as if nothing happens.

Comment: You should pass a JavaScript name/value object as the value of `data`; it shouldn't just be a string unless it's in the form of a URL query string.

Comment: @Pointy, can you post that in an answer?

Comment: @Pointy you can pass a JSON string if the server expects it

Comment: @epascarello yes of course, but I think that's probably not the case here judging by that server-side code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

In a jQuery `$.ajax()` call, the `data` property should be either

- a URL-style query string ("foo=bar&hello=world");
- a plain object (`{ foo: "bar", hello: "world" }`);
- an array of objects with `name` and `value` properties

  ```
  [ { name: "foo", value: "bar" },
    { name: "hello", value: "world" }]
  ```

Your code is building a JSON string, and I don't think it should be.